# C++ Double size/ overflow questions

Tags: c++, floating-point, double

I have recently come across something weird that I am having trouble understanding.

Basically I was trying to estimate the number of seconds that have passed in the last 2014 years. However the results that I was getting were negative numbers. I thought at first that it was some kind of overflow due to the size limitations of a double floating point variable, however after looking into that it seems that this is not the case. So I started to play around with the following code:

```
double test = 1.8*pow(10,308);
cout << test << endl;
test = 1.7*pow(10,308);
cout << test << endl;
test = 2*1000000000;
cout << test << endl;
test = 2*100*100*100*100*100;
cout << test << endl;
test = 1*1000000000;
cout << test << endl;
test = 1*100*100*100*100*100;
cout << test << endl;
```

This returned the following output:

```
inf
1.7e+308
2e+009
-1.47484e+009
1e+009
1.41007e+009
```

The first two results make sense to me. I am under the impression that 1.7e+308 is the maximum possible value that can be stores in a double, which means that 1.8e+308 wouldn't work - so the compiler interprets this as infinity?
However after that things become a little confusing.

I don't understand why 2*10000000000 and 2*100*100*100*100*100 return different values?

Or why 1*10000000000 and 1*100*100*100*100*100 don't return that same value?

I also don't understand why 2*100*100*100*100*100 returns a negative value?

Also where is the 1.4... coming from when I am only multiplaying by 1 or 2?

If someone could help me understand this better it would be appreciated!

Comment: Because `100` is an `int`, so the multiplication overflows.

Comment: BTW: the estimate for the number of seconds since 2014 (2014 * 365.2425 * 24 * 3600) is 63555701328 and fits best in a long long int.  If you made a similar calculation and put it in a double, then you see an integer overflow as already explained by Mike.

Comment: If you're only trying to estimate: π seconds is a nano-century;
in other words, there are roughly 3E09 seconds in a century, or
60E09 seconds in 2000 years.  (For a more exact estimation, use
`long long`.  But it won't be exact either.)

Comment: @stefaanv why would a double not also work? As I understand it, because 63555701328 is less than 1.7e+308, if I use floating point constants for my calculation, double should still be able to hold the number without having an overflow?

Comment: @JamesAllingham No overflow with double, but typically, a double will only have about 52 bits precision, so you might get some rounding.  (In general, if you don't need or expect a fractional part, use an integral type.  If there isn't one big enough, scale the input data.)

Comment: @JamesAllingham: it will work with double, but if you're not interested in fractions of second, then integer types are a better fit and long long int is at least 64 bit, so it has plenty of space for seconds (584554049253 year) .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All of these except the first two are performing integer arithmetic, then converting the integer result to `double`. The strange values are the result of integer overflow (which gives undefined behaviour). You should get the results you expect if you use floating-point constants, for example

```
test = 2. * 100. * 100. * 100. * 100. * 100.;
```

Comment: Oh ok. Thanks! Could you tell me what the reason is for doing integer arithmetic even for a variable that has been declared a double? Also is this integer overflow related to the size of an integer or a long int?

Comment: @JamesAllingham: The type of an arithmetic operation is determined only by the operands (e.g. `2` and `100`), which are integers here. It's only converted to `double` when you assign the result to `test`.

Comment: "Also is this integer overflow related to the size of an integer or a long int?" The arithmetic might use `int`, `long`, or `long long` (and perhaps `unsigned` versions), depending on the values of the constants. `2` and `100` are small enough to fit in `int`, so that will be used there. Larger values might need larger types to represent them.

Comment: And any value can be forced to a desired type: `2LL`, for example.